# How do I make sure that the file is closed after open in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How do I make sure that the open file is closed after use?

I am using the following codes to open and write files:

```
        var mFile:File = new File ();
        var actvityDirectoryXMLFile:File = mFile.resolvePath ( filePath );
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream ();

        stream.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE , onFileWriteComplete );
        stream.open ( actvityDirectoryXMLFile , FileMode.WRITE );
        stream.writeUTFBytes ( xml.toXMLString ());
        stream.close ();
        stream.openAsync ( actvityDirectoryXMLFile , FileMode.READ );
        mFile = null;
        actvityDirectoryXMLFile = null;
```

My problem is that if i am saving my lessons first time then it is saving the lessons perfectly but after modification if i am saving the same lessons again then I am getting the following Error:

"Error: Error #3013: File or directory is in use. at flash.filesystem"

I don't know why it is showing like this as I have already written `stream.close ();` after file write.

So anybody have an idea why it is showing like this or how to solve this problem.

Comment: you open then close then open again, the last operation is the one that counts.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all related code. What does `onFileWriteComplete` look like? On what exact line do you get the error? [Use the debugger to step through your code](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/debugging-actionscript-3-0.html).

Answer (score 0):

as soon as you write the file you are opening the file using the following code

```
stream.openAsync ( actvityDirectoryXMLFile , FileMode.READ );
```

so remove it , it is the reason your file is opwn right now or use `stream.close ();` after that line like the following code

```
    var mFile:File = new File ();
    var actvityDirectoryXMLFile:File = mFile.resolvePath ( filePath );
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream ();

    stream.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE , onFileWriteComplete );
    stream.open ( actvityDirectoryXMLFile , FileMode.WRITE );
    stream.writeUTFBytes ( xml.toXMLString ());
    stream.close ();
    //stream.openAsync ( actvityDirectoryXMLFile , FileMode.READ );
    mFile = null;
    actvityDirectoryXMLFile = null;
```

or the following code

```
    var mFile:File = new File ();
    var actvityDirectoryXMLFile:File = mFile.resolvePath ( filePath );
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream ();

    stream.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE , onFileWriteComplete );
    stream.open ( actvityDirectoryXMLFile , FileMode.WRITE );
    stream.writeUTFBytes ( xml.toXMLString ());
    stream.close ();
    stream.openAsync ( actvityDirectoryXMLFile , FileMode.READ );
    stream.close ();
    mFile = null;
    actvityDirectoryXMLFile = null;
```